# How to clear URL variables in php

Tags: php, getmethod

```
if (isset($_GET['add']) && isset($_GET['price']) && isset($_GET['qty'])){

    $ITEM = array(
      //Item name       
      'name' => $_GET['add'], 
      //Item Price
      'price' => $_GET['price'], 
      //Qty wanted of item
      'qty' => $_GET['qty']     
         );
     $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'][] =  $ITEM;
```

An item is added in cart when page is refresh. any one help how to remove url variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex mentions from a http protocol perspective you should use POST requests to update your cart.

Keep in mind that the problem persists using GET or POST request. POST are even more anoying because and alert is displayed to the customer.

To avoid that refreshing the page in the browser the shopping cart gets another duplicated item you can choose for example :

- Sends a redirection (301,302) after adding the item to the browser to clean the vars from the url/request
- Use AJAX to add items to the shopping cart

Answer (score 1):

A `POST` request is designed to update the server's state.

A `GET` request is not.

You are using the wrong tool for the job. Adding an item to your shopping cart should be a `POST` request.

Comment: Maybe he is changing the URL of an iframe to not refresh the main page, and pass a request to the server without using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: thanx alex. But i adding the item through 'add to cart' option which is a hyper link not a form.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan That's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @ajay You can make a form submit look like a hyperlink.

Comment: $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = ""; may be a  solution for clear the url variable?

Comment: @ajay That is patching an existing design problem.

Comment: just get the hyperlink and send a jquery $.post the addtocart; avoid that GET way.